# multipath iSCSI cleanup code

Tags: python

I know only the very basics of python. I have this project for my INFORMATION STORAGE AND MANAGEMENT subject. I have to give an explanation the following code.

I searched every command used in this script but could not find most of them. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/emc-openstack/vnx-faulty-device-cleanup/blob/master/faulty_device_cleanup.py):

```
import glob
import json
import os
import re
import string
import sys

from oslo.config import cfg

from nova import context
from nova.db.sqlalchemy import api as db_api
from nova.db.sqlalchemy import models
from nova import utils

CONF = cfg.CONF


def usage():
    print("""
Usage:
     python %s --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf

Note: This script intends to clean up the iSCSI multipath faulty devices
hosted by VNX Block Storage.""" % sys.argv[0])


class FaultyDevicesCleaner(object):
    def __init__(self):
       # Get host name of Nova computer node.
       self.host_name = self._get_host_name()

    def _get_host_name(self):
        (out, err) = utils.execute('hostname')
        return out

    def _get_ncpu_emc_target_info_list(self):
        target_info_list = []
        # Find the targets used by VM on the compute node
        bdms = db_api.model_query(context.get_admin_context(),
                              models.BlockDeviceMapping,
                              session = db_api.get_session())
        bdms = bdms.filter(models.BlockDeviceMapping.connection_info !=   None)
        bdms = bdms.join(models.BlockDeviceMapping.instance).filter_by(
             host=string.strip(self.host_name))

        for bdm in bdms:
            conn_info = json.loads(bdm.connection_info)

            if 'data' in conn_info:
                if 'target_iqns' in conn_info['data']:
                    target_iqns = conn_info['data']['target_iqns']
                    target_luns = conn_info['data']['target_luns']
                elif 'target_iqn' in conn_info['data']:
                    target_iqns = [conn_info['data']['target_iqn']]
                    target_luns = [conn_info['data']['target_lun']]
                else:
                   target_iqns = []
                   target_luns = []
                for target_iqn, target_lun in zip(target_iqns, target_luns):
                   if 'com.emc' in target_iqn:
                        target_info = {
                           'target_iqn': target_iqn,
                           'target_lun': target_lun,
                        }
                        target_info_list.append(target_info)

        return target_info_list

     def _get_ncpu_emc_target_info_set(self):
        target_info_set = set()
        for target_info in self._get_ncpu_emc_target_info_list():
            target_iqn = target_info['target_iqn']
            target_lun = target_info['target_lun']
            target_info_key = "%s-%s" % (target_iqn.rsplit('.', 1)[0],
                                     target_lun)
            # target_iqn=iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.fnm00130200235.a7
            # target_lun=203
            # target_info_key=iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.fnm00130200235-203
            target_info_set.add(target_info_key)
        return target_info_set

  def _get_target_info_key(self, path):
      temp_tuple = path.split('-lun-', 1)
      target_lun = temp_tuple[1]
      target_iqn = temp_tuple[0].split('-iscsi-')[1]
      target_info_key = "%s-%s" % (target_iqn.rsplit('.', 1)[0], target_lun)
      # path=/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.3.52:3260-iscsi-iqn.1992-
      # 04.com.emc:cx.fnm00130200235.a7-lun-203
    # target_info_key=iqn.1992-04.com.emc:cx.fnm00130200235-203
       return target_info_key

 def _get_non_ncpu_target_info_map(self):
    # Group the paths by target_info_key
    ncpu_target_info_set = self._get_ncpu_emc_target_info_set()
    device_paths = self._get_emc_device_paths()
    target_info_map = {}
    for path in device_paths:
        target_info_key = self._get_target_info_key(path)
        if target_info_key in ncpu_target_info_set:
            continue
        if target_info_key not in target_info_map:
            target_info_map[target_info_key] = []
        target_info_map[target_info_key].append(path)
    return target_info_map

def _all_related_paths_faulty(self, paths):
    for path in paths:
        real_path = os.path.realpath(path)
        out, err = self._run_multipath(['-ll', real_path],
                                       run_as_root=True,
                                       check_exit_code=False)
        if 'active ready' in out:
            # At least one path is still working
            return False
    return True

def _delete_all_related_paths(self, paths):
    for path in paths:
        real_path = os.path.realpath(path)
        device_name = os.path.basename(real_path)
        device_delete = '/sys/block/%s/device/delete' % device_name
        if os.path.exists(device_delete):
            # Copy '1' from stdin to the device delete control file
            utils.execute('cp', '/dev/stdin', device_delete,
                          process_input='1', run_as_root=True)
        else:
            print "Unable to delete %s" % real_path

def _cleanup_faulty_paths(self):
    non_ncpu_target_info_map = self._get_non_ncpu_target_info_map()
    for paths in non_ncpu_target_info_map.itervalues():
        if self._all_related_paths_faulty(paths):
            self._delete_all_related_paths(paths)

def _cleanup_faulty_dm_devices(self):
    out_ll, err_ll = self._run_multipath(['-ll'],
                                         run_as_root=True,
                                         check_exit_code=False)
    # Pattern to split the dm device contents as follows
    #     Each section starts with a WWN and ends with a line with
    #     "  `-" as the prefix
    #
    # 3600601601bd032007c097518e96ae411 dm-2 ,
    # size=1.0G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
    # `-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
    #   `- #:#:#:# -   #:#   active faulty running
    # 36006016020d03200bb93e048f733e411 dm-0 DGC,VRAID
    # size=1.0G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
    # |-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=130 status=active
    # | |- 3:0:0:2 sdd 8:48  active ready  running
    # | `- 5:0:0:2 sdj 8:144 active ready  running
    # `-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=10 status=enabled
    #   |- 4:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  active ready  running
    #   `- 6:0:0:2 sdm 8:192 active ready  running
    dm_pat = r'([0-9a-fA-F]{30,})[^\n]+,[^\n]*\n[^,]*  `-[^\n]*'
    dm_m = re.compile(dm_pat)
    path_pat = r'- \d+:\d+:\d+:\d+ '
    path_m = re.compile(path_pat)
    for m in dm_m.finditer(out_ll):
        if not path_m.search(m.group(0)):
            # Only #:#:#:# remain in the output, all the paths of the dm
            # device should have been deleted. No need to keep the device
            out_f, err_f = self._run_multipath(['-f', m.group(1)],
                                               run_as_root=True,
                                               check_exit_code=False)

def cleanup(self):
    self._cleanup_faulty_paths()
    # Make sure the following configuration is in /etc/multipath.conf
    # Otherwise, there may be "map in use" failure when deleting
    # dm device
    #
    # defaults {
    #   flush_on_last_del yes
    # }
    #
    self._cleanup_faulty_dm_devices()

def _get_emc_device_paths(self):
    # Find all the EMC iSCSI devices under /dev/disk/by-path
    # except LUNZ and partition reference
    pattern = '/dev/disk/by-path/ip-*-iscsi-iqn*com.emc*-lun-*'
    device_paths = [path for path in glob.glob(pattern)
                    if ('lun-0' not in path and '-part' not in path)]
    return device_paths

def _run_multipath(self, multipath_command, **kwargs):
    check_exit_code = kwargs.pop('check_exit_code', 0)
    (out, err) = utils.execute('multipath',
                               *multipath_command,
                               run_as_root=True,
                               check_exit_code=check_exit_code)
    print ("multipath %(command)s: stdout=%(out)s stderr=%(err)s"
           % {'command': multipath_command, 'out': out, 'err': err})

    return out, err

if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv) != 3 or sys.argv[1] != '--config-file':
    usage()
    exit(1)

out, err = utils.execute('which', 'multipath', check_exit_code=False)
if 'multipath' not in out:
    print('Info: Multipath tools not installed. No cleanup need be done.')
    exit(0)

multipath_flush_on_last_del = False
multipath_conf_path = "/etc/multipath.conf"
if os.path.exists(multipath_conf_path):
    flush_on_last_del_yes = re.compile(r'\s*flush_on_last_del.*yes')
    for line in open(multipath_conf_path, "r"):
        if flush_on_last_del_yes.match(line):
            multipath_flush_on_last_del = True
            break
if not multipath_flush_on_last_del:
    print("Warning: 'flush_on_last_del yes' is not seen in"
          " /etc/multipath.conf."
          " 'map in use' failure may show up during cleanup.")

CONF(sys.argv[1:])

# connect_volume and disconnect_volume in nova/virt/libvirt/volume.py
# need be adjusted to take the same 'external=True' lock for
# synchronization
@utils.synchronized('connect_volume', external=True)
def do_cleanup():
    cleaner = FaultyDevicesCleaner()
    cleaner.cleanup()
do_cleanup()
```

Comment: you should not try to understand 50-100 lines of code unless you are quite familiar with the language and it's syntax, it seems that you have practised much on Python , choose some other language of your interest

Comment: I cannot select my language of interest.It is assigned to me as project and it is mandatory to explain.Is there any tutorial or website that helps in finding meaning of above used commands

Comment: How much do you understand python? And what should I understand by basic?

Comment: In function def _get_ncpu_emc_target_info_set(self):  i am not understanding meaning of any line .I know for loop,if stmt,join,append,strip fun but rest i m completely unaware.

Comment: I will be better for you to Youtube some python videos. There are many there even some of google developers from basic. You can easily learn python in a day.

Comment: i will surely upvote your comment.

Comment: bdms = db_api.model_query(context.get_admin_context(),
                              models.BlockDeviceMapping,
                              session = db_api.get_session())
        bdms = bdms.filter(models.BlockDeviceMapping.connection_info !=   None)  what is going in these line.SOME databse connectivity is happening but i m not getting anythig

Comment: How to upvote comments.I m not seeing any option for it

Comment: I am sending you some good links for python try that buddy :)

Comment: yes i understand hindi

Comment: i m not able to upvote ur answer.It says i need atleast 15 reputation to upvote any answer and i don't have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers
http://www.astro.ufl.edu/~warner/prog/python.html

looks like this python version 3 so. go for the tutorials of version three.
try downloading any IDE. eric5 is good by the way.

try executing this file once.

learn indentations
and dynamic variable declaration
do not jump into the ocean first try swimming pool : )

Answer (score 0):

Also Try to learn method declaration.
Python is a bit different than java.
I will give you a hint looks like system call are also made to execute os commands so try looking at subprocess and how its output is directed to an output stream and error stream.